# Tag Synonym Request: [autoproperties] > [auto-properties]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

Please add the [autoproperties](/questions/tagged/autoproperties) tag as a synonym of the [auto-properties](/questions/tagged/auto-properties) tag.

See [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) if you need more info.

Answer (score 2):

Already completed earlier.....